# Safari slow on closing tabs

Tags: safari

Safari v 16

OSX v 12.6

Safari works normally in Opening new tabs or reloading the page.

However it hangs up and it even shows the death wheel while trying to close a TAB, any tab, it eventually it closes the tab with significant delay.

It is not the Internet, since it loads fine, and Chrome works.

Cleared Cookies, Cleared History

Did not clear Cache (yet)

No Extensions installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the culprit - Solved

Some [contaminated website](https://www.pickhvac.com/hvac-duct/cfm-calculator/) (do not use) was doing that.

Comment: Mark this as the “accepted” answer rather than put a heading that says “solved”